# easy beautiful chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I asked a question on this site "[JavaScript not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7702241/javascript-not-working-as-expected)": link:

I could not find any solution, because I want to use g.raphael and line chart as a matter. But I could not find a solution that works. Even in their demo site, nothing is displayed. For me, I tested, don't know how much right, tested g.raphael.piechart and line chart, but could not get result. I tried use another site: I could not see any result when I tried copying instruction and downloaded js.

This is what I test: http://joedesigns.com/labs/Beautiful-Analytics-Chart/

Can anybody introduce me to another chart lib that is easy to use and more beautiful?

Comment: the charts on the page you linked are working perfectly for me. What browser are you testing it with?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, these seem to be working, may just be your browser, but another good charting solution may be:

http://www.highcharts.com/